How to Create a Wavy, Gel-Like Transparent Material with a Mysterious Glow?
I am trying to do some practice as a beginner in Blender, and I have come across a very cute creature on the internet.

The problem though is that I can not replicate the same wavy material she is made from - I see that i have to make first an inner body, the orange one, then another duplicate which shrinkwraps it and has a transparent gel texture with a wavy displacement (idk?) and a higher IOR, and the cap with a glass texture. The one with the wavy look disturbs me more, as I have not seen any tutorials anywhere similar to this thing. Any ideas? Would be very grateful!

As I see, there is no way to replicate it through voronoi and noise texture. Here is what i have so far:
If I still get to model the texture by myself, is there a way to make the glass shader more colourful in thicker places? Super sad though it can't be something procedural.


It's not really the material that is difficult here. It's the modelling. You still have to model all the things you see. The material could be made of GlassBSDF shaders with different roughness and maybe some gradients What do you have as far? Could you share a screenshot?

The glass material probably has some volumetrics to make the color more intense on thicker parts and less on thinner parts. And I agree with @MartynasŽiemys that you also have to model this stuff... I'm not entirely sure the wavy part is just from the material... but if that image is the only reference, it's hard to tell.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
